# Unable to enable globstar in Bash 4

Tags: bash, bash4, shopt

I put the following unsuccessfully to my .bashrc

```
shopt -s globstar
```

I am trying to test the command in action by

```
ls **/*.c
```

and by comparing it to

```
ls */*/*.c
```

**How can you enable globstar in Bash 4?**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Hmm. `shopt -s globstar` should work.

To debug, make sure you are running Bash 4:

```
$SHELL --version
```

Then check the setting of `globstar`:

```
shopt globstar
```

If it is unset, try setting it manually:

```
shopt -s globstar
```

Now see if that works. If it does, you might want to look into why your `.bashrc` isn't working. Did you remember to restart you shell after editing your `.bashrc`, or load it with `. .bashrc`?

Comment: Thank you! I apparently did not remember to restart my shell.

Comment: `$0 --version` does not work. You should type `echo $0` or `$SHELL --version` to verify your shell

Comment: To disable: `shopt -u globstar`.

Comment: `line 1: shopt: globstar: invalid shell option name`