# Find all files containing a specific text (string) on Linux?

Tags: linux, text, grep, directory, find

How do I find all files containing a specific string of text within their file contents?

The following doesn't work. It seems to display every single file in the system.

```
find / -type f -exec grep -H 'text-to-find-here' {} \;
```

Comment: remember that grep will interpret any `.` as a single-character wildcard, among others. My advice is to alway use either fgrep or egrep.

Comment: anyway, you were almost there! Just replace `-H` with `-l` (and maybe `grep` with `fgrep`). To exclude files with certain patterns of names you would use `find` in a more advanced way. It's worthwile to learn to use `find`, though. Just `man find`.

Comment: `find … -exec <cmd> +` is easier to type and faster than `find … -exec <cmd> \;`. It works only if `<cmd>` accepts any number of file name arguments. The saving in execution time is especially big if `<cmd>` is slow to start like Python or Ruby scripts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use grep to find a word inside a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121803/how-can-i-use-grep-to-find-a-word-inside-a-folder)

Answer (score 13589, accepted):

Do the following:

```sh
grep -Rnw '/path/to/somewhere/' -e 'pattern'
```

- `-r` or `-R` is recursive ; use `-R` to search entirely
- `-n` is line number, and
- `-w` stands for match the whole word.
- `-l` (lower-case L) can be added to just give the file name of matching files.
- `-e` is the pattern used during the search

Along with these, `--exclude`, `--include`, `--exclude-dir` flags could be used for efficient searching:

- This will only search through those files which have .c or .h extensions:

  ```sh
  grep --include=\*.{c,h} -rnw '/path/to/somewhere/' -e "pattern"
  ```
- This will exclude searching all the files ending with .o extension:

  ```sh
  grep --exclude=\*.o -rnw '/path/to/somewhere/' -e "pattern"
  ```
- For directories it's possible to exclude one or more directories using the `--exclude-dir` parameter. For example, this will exclude the dirs `dir1/`, `dir2/` and all of them matching `*.dst/`:

  ```sh
  grep --exclude-dir={dir1,dir2,*.dst} -rnw '/path/to/search/' -e "pattern"
  ```

This works very well for me, to achieve almost the same purpose like yours.

For more options, see [`man grep`](https://ss64.com/bash/grep.html).

Comment: use --exclude. like "grep -rnw --exclude=*.o 'directory' -e "pattern"

Comment: it's worth noting: it seems the `r` option is lazy (traverses depth-first, than stops after the first directory), while `R` is greedy (will traverse the entire tree correctly).

Comment: Note(especially for newbies): The quotation marks in the above command are important.

Comment: For me it was useful to add the `-I` option to skip all binary files.

Comment: `-rnw` is case-sensitive and whole word only.  For a broader search change `-rnw` to `-rni` yielding matches for whole or partial words regardless of letter case.

Answer (score 2294):

Use `grep -ilR`:

```bash
grep -Ril "text-to-find-here" /
```

- `i` stands for ignore case (optional in your case).
- `R` stands for recursive.
- `l` stands for "show the file name, not the result itself".
- `/` stands for starting at the root of your machine.

Comment: Based on my experience, the `-i` makes it slow down a lot, so don't use it if not necessary. Test it in a certain dir and then generalise. It should be completed within few minutes. I think a regular expression would make it slower. But my comments are based on suppositions, I suggest you to test it with `time` in front of the line.

Comment: You can replace / with path to directory `grep -Ril "text-to-find-here" ~/sites/` or use . for current directory `grep -Ril "text-to-find-here" .`

Comment: Very slow though. Not recommended for large file systems.

Comment: on my distro grep used lowercase "R" so it was => `grep -ril "name" /`, but uppercase R didn't work.

Answer (score 469):

You can use [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/). It is like [grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) for source code. You can scan your entire file system with it.

Just do:

```bash
ack 'text-to-find-here'
```

In your root directory.

You can also use [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), specify the filetype, etc.

---

**UPDATE**

I just discovered [The Silver Searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher), which is like ack but 3-5x faster than it and even ignores patterns from a `.gitignore` file.

Comment: Very useful, simple and fast. Warning: "On Debian-derived distros, ack is packaged as "ack-grep" because "ack" already existed" (from http://beyondgrep.com/install/). You may end up running a Kanji code converter on those Linuxes...

Comment: ack or ack-grep has nice highlights, but find+grep when proper used is much better in performance

Comment: Note that [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) is faster than anything else mentioned here, including The Silver Searcher and plain 'ol grep. See [this blog post](http://blog.burntsushi.net/ripgrep/) for proof.

Comment: on Ubuntu and LinuxMint, use $ `ag 'what I want' ./`

Answer (score 298):

You can use:

```bash
grep -r "string to be searched" /path/to/dir
```

The `r` stands for recursive and so will search in the path specified and also its sub-directories. This will tell you the file name as well as print out the line in the file where the string appears.

Or a command similar to the one you are trying (example: ) for searching in all javascript files (*.js):

```
find . -name '*.js' -exec grep -i 'string to search for' {} \; -print
```

This will print the lines in the files where the text appears, but it does not print the file name.

In addition to this command, we can write this too:
**grep -rn "String to search" /path/to/directory/or/file**
*-r: recursive search*
*n: line number will be shown for matches*

Comment: Thank you for the 'find' version! It is so important to be able to filter by '*.js' or '*.txt', etc. Nobody wants to spend hours waiting for grep to finish searching all the multi-gigabyte videos from the last family vacation, even if the command is easier to type.

Answer (score 168):

Recursive and case insensitive grep with line numbers:

```bash
grep -inr "Text" folder/to/be/searched/
```

Comment: if you add -A3 is even better

Comment: **-i** is for case insensitive, **-n** shows the line number and **-r** recursive reads all the file in subdirectory

Answer (score 137):

#### [`grep`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/grep) ([GNU](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/) or [BSD](https://wiki.freebsd.org/BSDgrep))

You can use `grep` tool to search recursively the current folder, like:

```bash
grep -r "class foo" .
```

<sup>Note: `-r` - Recursively search subdirectories.</sup>

You can also use globbing syntax to search within specific files such as:

```bash
grep "class foo" **/*.c
```

<sup>Note: By using [globbing option](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option) (`**`), it scans all the files recursively with specific extension or pattern. **To enable this syntax, run: [`shopt -s globstar`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/793715/55075).** You may also use `**/*.*` for all files (excluding hidden and without extension) or any other pattern.</sup>

If you've the error that your argument is too long, consider narrowing down your search, or use `find` syntax instead such as:

```bash
find . -name "*.php" -execdir grep -nH --color=auto foo {} ';'
```

Alternatively, use [`ripgrep`](https://blog.burntsushi.net/ripgrep/).

#### [`ripgrep`](https://blog.burntsushi.net/ripgrep/)

If you're working on larger projects or big files, you should use `ripgrep` instead, like:

```bash
rg "class foo" .
```

<sup>Checkout the docs, installation steps or source code on the [GitHub project page](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep).</sup>

It's much quicker than any other tool like [GNU](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/)/[BSD](https://wiki.freebsd.org/BSDgrep) [`grep`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/grep), [`ucg`](https://github.com/gvansickle/ucg), [`ag`](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher), [`sift`](https://github.com/svent/sift), [`ack`](https://github.com/petdance/ack2), [`pt`](https://github.com/monochromegane/the_platinum_searcher) or similar, since it is built on top of [Rust's regex engine](https://github.com/rust-lang/regex) which uses finite automata, SIMD and aggressive literal optimizations to make searching very fast.

It supports ignore patterns specified in `.gitignore` files, so a single file path can be matched against multiple glob patterns simultaneously.

---

You can use common parameters such as:

- `-i` - Insensitive searching.
- `-I` - Ignore the binary files.
- `-w` - Search for the whole words (in the opposite of partial word matching).
- `-n` - Show the line of your match.
- `-C`/`--context` (e.g. `-C5`) - Increases context, so you see the surrounding code.
- `--color=auto` - Mark up the matching text.
- `-H` - Displays filename where the text is found.
- `-c` - Displays count of matching lines. Can be combined with `-H`.

Comment: I also find extended globbing useful. But keep in mind that if there are really huge number of files, you can get a "Argument list too long" error. (Simple globbing is also prone to this kind of error).

Answer (score 123):

### List of file names containing a given text

First of all, I believe you have used `-H` instead of `-l`. Also you can try adding the text inside quotes followed by `{} \`.

```
find / -type f -exec grep -l "text-to-find-here" {} \;
```

### Example

Let's say you are searching for files containing specific text "Apache License" inside your directory. It will display results somewhat similar to below (output will be different based on your directory content).

```
bash-4.1$ find . -type f -exec grep -l "Apache License" {} \; 
./net/java/jvnet-parent/5/jvnet-parent-5.pom
./commons-cli/commons-cli/1.3.1/commons-cli-1.3.1.pom
./io/swagger/swagger-project/1.5.10/swagger-project-1.5.10.pom
./io/netty/netty-transport/4.1.7.Final/netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.pom
./commons-codec/commons-codec/1.9/commons-codec-1.9.pom
./commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.pom
bash-4.1$
```

### Remove case sensitiveness

Even if you are not use about the case like "text" vs "TEXT", you can use the `-i` switch to ignore case. You can read further details [here](http://www.digizol.com/2010/10/linux-find-content-filenames-search.html).

Comment: Which is what this command does: `find` will pass all the paths it finds to the command `grep -l "text-to-find-here" <file found>"`. You may add restrictions to the file name, e.g. `find / -iname "*.txt"` to search only in files which name ends in `.txt`

Comment: @Auxiliary - included a sample output to avoid any confusion for the readers.

Comment: @Mene It's a truly sad state that Auxiliary's comment has more votes than yours...even if their comment is from 2014 and yours is 2017 that their comment has 6 when it should have exactly 0 and yours only had one (now two) isn't something I'd like to believe.

Comment: @Mene That being said *`-iname`* is case-insensitive which means it would also find .TXT files, for example, as well as TxT and TXt and so on.

Answer (score 79):

This grep command will give you a precise result when you are searching for specific text on Linux -

*`grep -inRsH "Text to be searched"  /path/to/dir (it can be '.')`*

- `i` stands for ignore case distinctions
- `R` stands for recursive and it also include symlinks. It is better to use 'R' instead of 'r'
- `n` stands for "it will print line number".
- `s` stands for "suppress error messages"
- `H` stands for "it will print the file name for each match"

Comment: but this doesn't display the "file" that contains that text

Comment: this combination will give you lineno, filename along with the text that you have searched. @FiruzzZ try it once

Answer (score 72):

If your `grep` doesn't support recursive search, you can combine `find` with `xargs`:

```
find / -type f | xargs grep 'text-to-find-here'
```

I find this easier to remember than the format for `find -exec`.

This will output the filename and the content of the matched line, e.g.

```
/home/rob/file:text-to-find-here
```

Optional flags you may want to add to `grep`:

- `-i` - case insensitive search
- `-l` - only output the filename where the match was found
- `-h` - only output the line which matched (not the filename)

Comment: This is equivalent to `grep 'text-to-find-here'` without file name if `find` does not find anything. This will hang and wait for user input! Add `--no-run-if-empty` as an option to `xargs`.

Comment: This combination of find and xargs does not work as intended if file or directory names contain spaces (characters that xargs interprets as separators). Use `find … -exec grep … +`. If you insist on using find together with xargs, use `-print0` and `-0`.

Answer (score 56):

There's a new utility called **The Silversearcher**

```bash
sudo apt install silversearcher-ag
```

It works closely with Git and other VCS. So you won't get anything in a *.git* or another directory.

You can simply use

```bash
ag "Search query"
```

And it will do the task for you!

Comment: Good call!. I downloaded it and used it first time. The output results are very informative and colourful and very helpfull. This prog will stay in my machine for ever. I have also put it on my "Install a new computer" list of programs. Cheers!!

Answer (score 55):

```bash
grep -insr "pattern" *
```

- `i`: Ignore case distinctions in both the PATTERN and the input files.
- `n`: Prefix each line of output with the 1-based line number within its input file.
- `s`: Suppress error messages about nonexistent or unreadable files.
- `r`: Read all files under each directory, recursively.

Comment: Can you explain how your answer improves upon the other answers, or how it is sufficiently different from them?

Comment: not much complex to remember, will cover all patterns(case-senstivity -> off, includes file-names and line number and will do recursively search etc) and using "*" in the end will search all directories (no need to specify any path or directory name).

Comment: Sorry, I should've been clearer: it would be great if you could include that explanation in your answer. As it stands, especially with so many other similar answers already, it is hard to see from such a short answer what the benefit of trying _it_ over the accepted answer or one of the upvoted ones would be.

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter One thing I love about this answer is pointing out the suppress argument, which can help filter out noise that doesn't matter to getting the results we actually want. Grep prints errors like, "Function not implemented", "Invalid Argument", "Resource unavailable", etc. etc on certain "files".

Comment: @leetNightshade: I'm assuming you're addressing your comment to me because I asked for an explanation on the sparse original post. Please see Fabio's great [revision](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35644413/revisions) for my previous comments to make sense.

Comment: I'm quite fond of ` -I Ignore binary files.`.

Answer (score 52):

> How do I find all files containing specific text on Linux?
> (...)
>
> I came across this solution twice:
>
> `find / -type f -exec grep -H 'text-to-find-here' {} \;`

---

If using **[find](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html)** like in your example, better add `-s` (`--no-messages`) to `grep`, and `2>/dev/null` at the end of the command to avoid lots of *Permission denied* messages issued by `grep` and `find`:

```
find / -type f -exec grep -sH 'text-to-find-here' {} \; 2>/dev/null
```

**[find](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html)** is the standard tool for searching files - combined with grep when looking for specific text - on Unix-like platforms. The [find](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) command is often combined with [xargs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html), by the way.

Faster and easier tools exist for the same purpose - see below. Better try them, *provided they're available on your platform*, of course:

### Faster and easier alternatives

**[RipGrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep)** - fastest search tool around:

```bash
rg 'text-to-find-here' / -l
```

**[The Silver Searcher](https://geoff.greer.fm/ag)**:

```bash
ag 'text-to-find-here' / -l
```

**[ack](https://beyondgrep.com/documentation)**:

```bash
ack 'text-to-find-here' / -l
```

Note: You can add `2>/dev/null` to these commands as well, to hide many error messages.

---

**Warning**: *unless you really can't avoid it, don't search from [**'/'** (the root directory)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_directory) to avoid a long and inefficient search!
So in the examples above, you'd better replace '**/**' by a sub-directory name, e.g. "/home" depending where you actually want to search...*

Answer (score 52):

Use `pwd` to search from any directory you are in, recursing downward

```bash
grep -rnw `pwd` -e "pattern"
```

Depending on the version of grep you are using, you can omit `pwd`. In newer versions `.` seems to be the default case for grep if no directory is given.

Thus:

`grep -rnw -e "pattern"`

or

`grep -rnw "pattern"`

will do the same thing as above!

Comment: using `pwd` is not necessary at all, since it is the default. `grep -rnw "pattern"` suffices.

Comment: and in fact the `grep -rnw` and similar is what was answered like three years ago, I don't see how this answer is adding value.

Comment: The selected answer does not show the default pattern, and 5 peoples seemed to have found it useful

Comment: What do you mean with "default pattern"? The accepted answer contains `grep -rnw '/path/to/somewhere/' -e "pattern"` which is what you have here. 5 votes after 2.3M visits does not mean that much.

Comment: I agree :-) what I was missing in the original answer is the use case that you don't have to give a path at all or to search the current directory recursively which is not reflected in the accepted answer. Thus it was a good learning experience about grep to dig a bit deeper.

Comment: OK, I see. It is not trivial to see that `grep "pattern"`  needs something to check (a dir, a file...) while `grep -R "pattern"` works standalone. Then probably an addition to the answer would benefit more people (last posts are rarely noticed). But I am glad you learned from it :) I have the 2nd most upvoted answer and I see there are many, many variants of doing this.

Comment: So with `pwd` I was trying to find an easy hack to not type in the full path, but I am sure `.` would suffice as well, as current directory, but leaving it out altogether is of course the leanest.

Comment: Actually I just now am running into issues where, if the path is not given, there is no output. Thus `pwd` is needed @fedorqui

Comment: `cd /tmp; mkdir mytest; cd mytest; mkdir a{1..3}; seq 10 > a1/a1; seq 10 > a1/a2; seq 10 > a2/a1` once you have all of this, do write `grep -rnw 5`. This works fine to me on GNU grep 2.16.

Comment: This is not working on grep 2.5.1 which I am currently working with  ...

Answer (score 39):

Try:

```bash
find . -name "*.txt" | xargs grep -i "text_pattern"
```

Comment: This is actually a prime example of when NOT to use `xargs` like that .. consider this.  ```echo "file bar.txt has bar" > bar.txt; echo "file foo bar.txt has foo bar" > "foo bar.txt"; echo "You should never see this foo" > foo; find . -name "*.txt" | xargs grep -i foo # 
./foo:You should never see this foo``` . The `xargs` here matched the WRONG file and did NOT match the intended file.  Either use a `find .. -print0 | xargs -0 ...` but that's a useless use of a pipe or better `find ... -exec grep ... {} +`

Answer (score 37):

```bash
grep -lrnw '/root/Desktop/ipozal' -e 'geolocation'
```

For example:

- my folder name is "*ipozal*"
- it placed on "*/root/Desktop*"
- I want to find this text on all files in it "*geolocation*"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider adding a description or explanation for this code block.

Comment: 1. backup your folder on desktop

Comment: 2. my project name is 'ipozal'

Comment: then use this command and replace 'ipozal' with your folder name, to find files that contains this text 'geolocation'

Comment: Good explanation -- you should edit your answer so that the explanation is included.

Comment: Please put the information from the comments into your answer (by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59418364/edit)). Stack Overflow is [not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 27):

`grep` can be used even if we're not looking for a string.

Simply running,

```bash
grep -RIl "" .
```

will print out the path to all text files, i.e. those containing only printable characters.

Comment: I don't see how this is better than using a mere `ls` or `find` (for the recursive)

Answer (score 27):

If you strictly want to use `find` then use `find + grep`:

`find /path/to/somewhere/ -type f -exec grep -nw 'textPattern' {} \;`

**Steps**:

1. Use `find` to search files,
2. Execute `grep` on all of them.

This gives you the power of `find` to find files.

- Use `-name Pattern` if you want to `grep` only certain files:

`find /path/to/somewhere/ -type f -name \*.cpp -exec grep -nw 'textPattern' {} \;`

You can use different options of `find` to improve your file search.

Comment: What is the difference? Will it work with spaces in the file path?

Comment: Does not provide filenames of found files.

Answer (score 26):

Silver Searcher is a terrific tool, but ripgrep may be even better.

It works on Linux, Mac and Windows, and was written up on [Hacker News](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker_News) a couple of months ago (this has a link to Andrew Gallant's Blog which has a GitHub link):

*[Ripgrep – A new command line search tool](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=12564442)*

Answer (score 24):

Here are the several list of commands that can be used to search file.

```
grep "text string to search” directory-path

grep [option] "text string to search” directory-path

grep -r "text string to search” directory-path

grep -r -H "text string to search” directory-path

egrep -R "word-1|word-2” directory-path

egrep -w -R "word-1|word-2” directory-path
```

Comment: what is this adding to the existing answers?

Comment: @fedorqui `egrep` is equivalent to `grep -E` and it means `--extended-regexp` you can find details here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/17951/196072

Answer (score 24):

There is the [ack](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ack) tool that would do exactly what you are looking for:

```
ack -i search_string folder_path/*
```

You may ignore `-i` for case sensitive search.

Comment: What is this adding to the existing answers? This was suggested more than three years ago already.

Comment: @fedorqui 1)no piping! 2)Use regular expressions 3)Get line numbers, file name with relative path, highlighted text etc. useful for editing after the search e.g "vim +lineno path/file.cpp" will get you right at the line no of interest. See the output of the  command "ack include\|hpp" that searches "include" or "hpp" keywords under my search folder and subfolders. I hope the point is clear. Here is the sample output(Can't show the keyword highlights with simple text)
process/child.hpp
11:boost/process/child.hpp
process/all.hpp
21:#include <boost/process/execute.hpp>

Answer (score 23):

I am fascinated by how simple [grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) makes it with 'rl':

```
grep -rl 'pattern_to_find' /path/where/to/find

-r to recursively find a file / directory inside directories..
-l to list files matching the 'pattern'
```

> Use '-r' without 'l' to see the file names followed by **text in which the pattern is found**!

```bash
grep -r 'pattern_to_find' /path/where/to/find
```

It works just perfect...

Comment: This also works in [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway) (Windows).

Comment: But it implies every file must searched (no filter on the file name or file extension level, like `.txt`). Or is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 22):

Expanding the `grep` a bit to give more information in the output, for example, to get the line number in the file where the text is can be done as follows:

```
find . -type f -name "*.*" -print0 | xargs --null grep --with-filename --line-number --no-messages --color --ignore-case "searthtext"
```

And if you have an idea what the file type is you can narrow your search down by specifying file type extensions to search for, in this case `.pas` OR `.dfm` files:

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.pas" -o -name "*.dfm" \) -print0 | xargs --null grep --with-filename --line-number --no-messages --color --ignore-case "searchtext"
```

Short explanation of the options:

1. `.` in the `find` specifies from the current directory.
2. `-name` "`*.*`" : for all files
   ( -name "`*.pas`" -o -name "`*.dfm`" ) : Only the `*.pas` OR `*.dfm` files, OR specified with `-o`
3. `-type f` specifies that you are looking for files
4. `-print0` and `--null` on the other side of the `|` (pipe) are the crucial ones, passing the filename from the `find` to the `grep` embedded in the `xargs`, allowing for the passing of filenames WITH spaces in the filenames, allowing grep to treat the path and filename as one string, and not break it up on each space.

Comment: `-name '*.*'` isn't what you say; it wouldn't pick up on a file called 'file' because the pattern doesn't equate to that (no .ext); `*` would however (well . files aside). But there's another thing: if you want all files why bother specifying a file name in the first place? No other comment - except that it's nice to know that there still are people who don't use the MS terminology 'folder' (which really after saying it enough I wouldn't add but I wanted to point out the slightly incorrect statement you made with file names - as well as the redundancy/uselessness in the case of 'all').

Comment: `print0` ought to be explained as well. Is it for spaces in the file names?

Answer (score 22):

If you are in a Git repository, you can use:

```
git grep something
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, does this only check files that are checked into `git` and/or not in the `.gitignore` file? Just checking to be sure because I love how handy this is in most development situations where the directory is already a `git` repo.

Comment: @JoshuaPinter recorded an asciicinema for you https://asciinema.org/a/g92UTPtL929ysb8umqPj9e2SA the idea is that git grep searchs what's in git, either commited or stashed. When you ignore a file and it's not commited or stashed it's not going to appear in the git grep

Comment: @Dorian Excellent. Thanks for confirming this thought. That could be a nasty gotcha if you're not aware of it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 22):

```bash
grep "text-to-find-here" file_name
```

or

```bash
grep "text-to-find-here" directory_path/*
```

If you want to search the current directory:

```bash
grep "text-to-find-here" *
```

Comment: Make sure to add an `-r` switch after `grep` if you're looking recursively into sub directories.

Answer (score 20):

A simple `find` can work handy. alias it in your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
alias ffind find / -type f | xargs grep
```

Start a new terminal and issue:

```bash
ffind 'text-to-find-here'
```

Answer (score 19):

```
find /path -type f -exec grep -l "string" {} \;
```

Explanation from comments

find is a command that lets you find files and other objects like directories and links in subdirectories of a given path. If you don't specify a mask that filesnames should meet, it enumerates all directory objects.

```
-type f specifies that it should proceed only files, not directories etc.
-exec grep specifies that for every found file, it should run grep command, passing its filename as an argument to it, by replacing {} with the filename
```

Answer (score 19):

Try:

```
find / -type f -exec grep -H 'text-to-find-here' {} \;
```

which will search all file systems, because `/` is the root folder.

For home folder use:

```
find ~/ -type f -exec grep -H 'text-to-find-here' {} \;
```

For current folder use:

```
find ./ -type f -exec grep -H 'text-to-find-here' {} \;
```

Comment: Perhaps the details on differences of folders are obvious to many ...but also very helpful for newbies. +1

Comment: what is this adding to the existing answers?

Comment: Call it my crusade but the word is 'directory'. This isn't Windows (which used to use 'directory' anyway - pre 9x). Please stop saying 'folder'. As for your last command you don't even need the '/' just FYI.

Answer (score 18):

[grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) is your good friend to achieve this.

```
grep -r <text_fo_find> <directory>
```

If you don't care about the case of the text to find, then use:

```
grep -ir <text_to_find> <directory>
```

Comment: In my case it looks like it searches everywhere even if I do specify the directory

Comment: @Pathros Probably to do with recursion enabled and what directory you specify. Put another way recursion does change things in that way.

Comment: @Pathros Oh and if there are any *`-`* s in the search string you'll want to pass in *`--`* to grep first; that can cause interesting side effects otherwise!

Answer (score 17):

I wrote a [Python script](https://github.com/dilawar/Scripts/blob/master/sniff.py) which does something similar. This is how one should use this script.

```
./sniff.py path pattern_to_search [file_pattern]
```

The first argument, `path`, is the directory in which we will search recursively. The second argument, `pattern_to_search`, is a regular expression which we want to search in a file. We use the regular expression format defined in the [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) `re` library. In this script, the `.` also matches newline.

The third argument, `file_pattern`, is optional. This is another regular expression which works on a filename. Only those files which matches this regular expression will be considered.

For example, if I want to search Python files with the extension `py` containing `Pool(` followed by word `Adaptor`, I do the following,

```
./sniff.py . "Pool(.*?Adaptor"  .*py
./Demos/snippets/cubeMeshSigNeur.py:146 
./Demos/snippets/testSigNeur.py:259 
./python/moose/multiscale/core/mumbl.py:206 
./Demos/snippets/multiComptSigNeur.py:268
```

And voila, it generates the path of matched files and line number at which the match was found. If more than one match was found, then each line number will be appended to the filename.

Answer (score 17):

To search for the string and output just that line with the search string:

```
for i in $(find /path/of/target/directory -type f); do grep -i "the string to look for" "$i"; done
```

e.g.:

```
for i in $(find /usr/share/applications -type f); \
do grep -i "web browser" "$i"; done
```

To display filename containing the search string:

```
for i in $(find /path/of/target/directory -type f); do if grep -i "the string to look for" "$i" > /dev/null; then echo "$i"; fi; done;
```

e.g.:

```
for i in $(find /usr/share/applications -type f); \
do if grep -i "web browser" "$i" > /dev/null; then echo "$i"; \
fi; done;
```

Comment: I see only downside compared to using `find … -exec grep 'str' {} \;` (if you have to use `find` at all).

Comment: This would break horribly if any of the files found by `find` contained spaces .. you could end up `grepping` the wrong files and/or missing the right files altogether.  Just use `find ... -exec grep ...` if you have a need to use `find` .. but in this case a `grep -r ...` suffices.

Comment: what is the point of using a loop over the results of find to then grep? This gets unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 17):

All previous answers suggest grep and find. But there is another way: Use [Midnight Commander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight_Commander)

It is a free utility (30 years old, proven by time) which is visual without being GUI. It has tons of functions, and finding files is just one of them.

Comment: ranger would be in the same idea

Answer (score 16):

The below command will work fine for this approach:

```
find ./ -name "file_pattern_name"  -exec grep -r "pattern" {} \;
```

Comment: what is the point of using `find` and then `grep -r`? They are meant for the same, so this is redundant.

Comment: ohh!! corrected , Actually find is for running grep  on filtered files and not all, thanks

Comment: still, this does not make any sense, you can filter with `find`.

Answer (score 16):

Use:

```
grep -c Your_Pattern *
```

This will report how many copies of your pattern are there in each of the files in the current directory.

Answer (score 16):

I tried the `grep` command below. It helps searching contents within my repository at `/etc/yum.repos.d`.

```bash
grep -Ril -e 'texttoSearch' /etc/yum.repos.d
```

Comment: It outputs files, but doesn't count them

Answer (score 15):

You can use below command as you don't want file name but you want to search from all the files. 
Here are i am capturing "TEXT" form All the log files making sure that file name is not printed

```
grep -e TEXT *.log | cut -d' ' --complement -s -f1
```

grep with -e option is quite quick compared to other option as it is for PATTERN match

Comment: Personally I think you should remove the *`#`* because other than comments that typically implies something - and you shouldn't be root unless you absolutely have to be. Even so you needn't have the prompt surely? Call this petty but I have seen people many times over the years simply copy and paste and do things without truly understanding it. Not saying any will here but still.. Just a thought.

Comment: Better way use find +  grep
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51023211/7918560

Answer (score 15):

Avoid the hassle and install ack-grep. It eliminates a lot of permission and quotation issues.

```bash
apt-get install ack-grep
```

Then go to the directory you want to search and run the command below

```bash
cd /
ack-grep "find my keyword"
```

Comment: Can you [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36169418/edit) the presumptions to the answer? On [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29)/[Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian)? What distribution and version was this tested on? [Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) (Xenial Xerus)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen ack-grep is available on any Linux disruption. All versions perform this basic functionality.

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```bash
find . | xargs grep 'word' -sl
```

Comment: this is far slower than the grep solution

Comment: @amine Yeah rather than using *`grep`* directly it pipes all the files *`find`* finds to xargs running *`grep`* on it. I'm sure you understand that but just to add to those who might not. The command here is .. I can't atm think of a good analogy but it's adding a lot of unnecessary and harmless overhead.

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
find / -type f -name "*" -exec grep -il "String_to_search" {} \;
```

Or

```bash
for i in /*;do grep -Ril "String_to_search" $i;done 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: what is this adding to the existing answers?

Comment: Good Question - Let start with top answers to this question. I tried below commands on AIX server with more than 15k files in log dir.

grep -rnw '/path/to/somewhere/' -e "pattern" >>> got the error "/usr/bin/grep: 0403-027 The parameter list is too long."

grep -Ril "text-to-find-here" /   >>> got the error "/usr/bin/grep: 0403-027 The parameter list is too long."

ack 'text-to-find-here'   >>> got the error "Segmentation fault(coredump)"

Comment: find / -type f -name "*" -exec grep -il "String_to_search" {} \;  >>> It will produce the result with filename and file data.

find / -type f -exec grep -H 'text-to-find-here' {} \;   >>> It will produce the result with filename only.

for i in /*;do grep -Ril "String_to_search" $i;done 2> /dev/null >>> It will work like grep -Ril "text-to-find-here" / but support large number of file.

Comment: @VIPINKUMAR **The parameter list is too long.** Yeah that's what *`xargs`* is for. Unsure on AIX if it has that though; no comment on your actual commands.

Answer (score 12):

`find` with `xarg`s is preferred when there are many potential matches to sift through. It runs more slowly than other options, but it always works. As some have discovered,`xargs` does not handle files with embedded spaces by default. You can overcome this by specifying the `-d` option.

Here is [@RobEarl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24323369), enhanced so it handles files with spaces:

```
find / -type f | xargs -d '\n' grep 'text-to-find-here'
```

Here is [@venkat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27394089), similarly enhanced:

```bash
find . -name "*.txt" | xargs -d '\n' grep -i "text_pattern"
```

Here is [@Gert van Biljon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28186178), similarly enhanced:

```
find . -type f -name "*.*" -print0 | xargs -d '\n' --null grep --with-filename --line-number --no-messages --color --ignore-case "searthtext"
```

Here is @LetalProgrammer's answer, similarly enhanced:

```
alias ffind find / -type f | xargs -d '\n' grep
```

Here is [@Tayab Hussain's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27481639), similarly enhanced:

```bash
find . | xargs -d '\n' grep 'word' -sl
```

Comment: [So `grep -rl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/how-do-i-find-all-files-containing-specific-text-on-linux/45564790#45564790) doesn't work with many matches?

Comment: "under many other Unix-like systems, arbitrarily long lists of parameters cannot be passed to a command, so the command may fail with an error message of "Argument list too long" (meaning that the exec system call's limit on the length of a command line was exceeded)"  ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs

Answer (score 11):

Use:

```bash
grep -Erni + "text you wanna search"
```

The command will search recursively in all files and directories of the current directory and print the result.

Note: if your grep output isn't colored, you can change it by using the `grep='grep --color=always'` `alias` in your shell source file.

Comment: You might want to point out that *`-i`* makes the search case-insensitive; by default it doesn't have that - nor should it as Unix (etc.) isn't a case-insensitive OS. You might also want to specify what the other options are for too.

Answer (score 10):

If you have a set of files that you will always be checking you can alias their paths, for example:

```
alias fd='find . -type f -regex ".*\.\(inc\|info\|module\|php\|test\|install\|uninstall\)"'
```

Then you can simply filter the list like this:

```bash
grep -U -l $'\015' $(fd)
```

Which filters out the list fd to files that contain the CR pattern.

I find that aliasing the files that I am interested in helps me create easier scripts then always trying to remember how to get all those files.  The recursive stuff works as well but sooner or later you are going to have to contend with weeding out specific file types.  Which is is why I just find all the file types I'm interested in to begin with.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the following commands to find particular text from a file:

```bash
cat file | grep 'abc' | cut -d':' -f2
```

Comment: the question is about finding which files contain a string, not about finding a string in a file.

Comment: And in any case this is a useless use of cat... http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html

Answer (score 10):

You can use [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) which will respect the default project's `.gitignore` file.

```
$ rg fast README.md
75:  faster than both. (N.B. It is not, strictly speaking, a "drop-in" replacement
88:  color and full Unicode support. Unlike GNU grep, ripgrep stays fast while
119:### Is it really faster than everything else?
124:Summarizing, ripgrep is `fast` because:
129:  optimizations to make searching very fast.
```

where `fast` keyword is highlighted in the terminal.

To suppress *Permission denied* errors:

```
$ rg -i rustacean 2> /dev/null
```

Which will redirect the [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr)) (stderr) output to `/dev/null`.

Comment: Re *"...respect the default project's .gitignore file"*: Can you provide a more complete description? 1) It presumably does more than that, like ignoring the content of the .git directory. 2) Must the search be done from the Git repository root folder? 3) What happens if not? Does it work like normal grep if outside a Git repository? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Comment: Please also review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*). It covers answers as well.

Answer (score 10):

My use case was to find Python code I had written way back that wrote jsonlines a particular way. I knew that `jsonl` would be part of the function name and `to_json` would appear in the body, but not much else.

Despite 50 answers, finding more than one string in the same file (whether or not in the same line) hasn't been answered.

The `-q` in grep is for quiet. Nothing is printed, only the return value is set. Thus the `-print` at the end. Each `-exec` only runs if the previous one succeeded. So if you have many files it pays to think about patterns that will eliminate files you aren't interested in.

```
find . -type f -name "*.py" \
  -exec grep -q -e 'to_json' {} \; \
  -exec grep -q -e 'def\s.*jsonl' {} \; \
  -print
```

Comment: Adding a small note for anybody passing by (and ignoring this like me in first instance): the space between \; is necessary or it will not work

Answer (score 9):

Try this

```
find . -type f -name some_file_name.xml -exec grep -H PUT_YOUR_STRING_HERE {} \;
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10250356)

Comment: @SergeyDenisov What gives? This is definitely an answer. (Whether it works or not is another matter.)

Comment: @jpaugh then you should explain it in details.

Comment: @SergeyDenisov. It gives a suggested course of action that might produce the correct result. Or, even if it does not, it might help someone else. That's what I mean by, "It's an answer." If you want to know how it works, ask the poster.

Comment: @SireeshYarlagadda You should provide more information in your answer, especially since this command is relatively complicated. Break it down into parts and explain each one. (It was flagged as low quality because it lacked an explanation.)

Comment: @jpaugh I'm sure that one line command/code is not enough for a complete answer. You could write a comment giving a suggested course of action, but an answer should include an explanation. That's why this answer was flagged as "Low Quality Post" (not by me).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95563/discussion-between-sergey-denisov-and-jpaugh).

Comment: @SergeyDenisov I agree with you on that! But I did not understand what you meant from the "canned" comment in the review tools.

Answer (score 9):

As [Peter in the previous answer mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/how-do-i-find-all-files-containing-specific-text-on-linux/44704863#44704863), all previous answers suggest grep and find.

But there is a more sophisticated way using [Gnome Commander](https://gcmd.github.io/) with a perfect **GUI** and with tons of options since 2001, and finding files is just one of them. It is a free utility as well, proven by time.

Answer (score 9):

**GUI Search Alternative - For Desktop Use:**

<sub>*- As the question is not precisely asking for commands*</sub>

**Searchmonkey**: Advanced file search tool without having to index your system using regular expressions. Graphical equivalent to find/grep. Available for Linux (Gnome/KDE/Java) and Windows (Java) - open source GPL v3

**Features:**

- <sub>Advanced Regular Expressions</sub>
- <sub>Results shown in-context</sub>
- <sub>Search containing text</sub>
- <sub>Panel to display line containing text</sub>
- <sub>New 2018 updates</sub>
- <sub>etc.</sub>

**Download - Links:**

- <sub>Homepage: http://searchmonkey.embeddediq.com/</sub>
- <sub>Download: http://searchmonkey.embeddediq.com/index.php/download-latest</sub>
- <sub>Repo: https://sourceforge.net/projects/searchmonkey/files/</sub>

.

**Screen-shot:**

[image]

Answer (score 9):

See also [The Platinium Searcher](https://github.com/monochromegane/the_platinum_searcher), which is similar to [The Silver Searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) and it's written in Go.

Example:

```bash
pt -e 'text to search'
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 9):

Try this command. Which will give you the files containing the pattern you entered.

```bash
sudo grep -inr "your-pattern" /
```

Here:
i - Ignore case distinctions, so that characters that differ only in case match each other.

n - Make  sure  that the first character of actual line content lies on a tab stop, so that the alignment of tabs looks normal.

r - Read  all  files  under each directory, recursively, following symbolic links only if they are on the command line.  Note that if no file operand is given, grep searches the working directory.

Answer (score 8):

> I'm trying to find a way to **scan my entire Linux system** for all files containing a specific string of text. ... Is this close to the proper way to do it? If not, how should I? ... This ability to find text strings in files would be extraordinarily useful for some programming projects I'm doing.

While you should never replace (or alias) a system command with a different program, due to risk of mysterious breakage of scripts or other utilities, if you are running a text search manually or from your own scripts or programs you should consider the fastest suitable program when searching a large number of files a number of times. Ten minutes to half an hour time spent installing and familiarizing yourself with a *better* utility can be recovered after a few uses for the use-case you described.

A webpage offering a "[Feature comparison of ack, ag, git-grep, GNU grep and ripgrep](https://beyondgrep.com/feature-comparison/)" can assist you to decide which program offers the features you need.

- Andrew Gallant's Blog claims: "[ripgrep is faster than {grep, ag, git grep, ucg, pt, sift}](https://blog.burntsushi.net/ripgrep/)" (a claim shared by some of the others, this is why a feature comparison is helpful). Of particular interest is his section on [regex implementations](https://blog.burntsushi.net/ripgrep/#regex-engine) and pitfalls.

  The following [command](https://blog.burntsushi.net/ripgrep/#whirlwind-tour) searches all files, including hidden and executable:

  `$ rg -uuu foobar`
- [The Silver Searcher](https://geoff.greer.fm/ag/) (ag) claims it is 5-10x faster than Ack. This program is suggested in some other answers. The GitHub doesn't appear as recent as ripgrep's and there are noticably more commits and branches with fewer releases, it's hard to draw an absolute claim based on those stats. The [short version](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=12567328): ripgrep is faster, but there's a tiny learning curve to not get caught by the differences.
- So what could be next, you guessed it, the [platinum searcher](https://github.com/monochromegane/the_platinum_searcher). The claims are: it searches code about 3–5× faster than ack, but its speed is equal to the silver searcher. It's written in GoLang and searches UTF-8, EUC-JP and Shift_JIS files; if that's of greater interest. The GitHub is neither particularly recent or active. GoLang itself has a fast and robust regex, but the platinum searcher would be better recommended if it had a better user interest.

For a combination of speed and power indexed query languages such as [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/what-is/elasticsearch) or [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) can be a long term [investment that pays off](https://www.searchtechnologies.com/blog/solr-vs-elasticsearch-top-open-source-search), but not if you want a quick and simple replacement for grep. OTOH both have an API which can be called from any program you write, adding powerful searches to your program.

While it's possible to spawn an external program, execute a search, intercept its output and process it, calling an API is the way to go for power and performance.

> `This question was protected Aug 6 '15 at 19:34 with this caution:`
>   We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations.

While some answers suggest alternative ways to accomplish a search they don't explain *why* other than it's "free", "faster", "more sophisticated", "tons of features", etc. Don't try to sell it, just tell us "why your answer is right". I've attempted to teach *how* to choose what's best for the user, and *why*. This is why I offer yet another answer, when there are already so many. Otherwise I'd agree that there are already quite a few answers; I hope I've brought a lot new to the table.

Answer (score 6):

Your command is correct. You just need to add `-l` to grep:

```
find / -type f -exec grep -l 'text-to-find-here' {} \;
```

Answer (score 5):

Kindly customize the below command according to demand and find any string recursively from files.

```
grep -i hack $(find /etc/ -type f)
```

Comment: Customise what parts? Your answer needs more explanation (see @rakib_'s answer for an example)

Comment: customise means  choose "hack"(searching string) keyword and /etc location according to your demand. you can also use below command
grep -ErIRi  hack  /*

Comment: This fails if a file name contains spaces.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is worth mentioning how you can find:

**All files containing at least one text, among a big set of texts:**

```
grep -rlf ../patternsFile.txt .
```

Output:

```
./file1
./file2
./file4
```

**The above, grouped by each text:**

```
cat ../patternsFile.txt | xargs -I{} sh -c "echo {}; grep -rl \"{}\" ."
```

Output:

```
pattern1
./file1
./file2
pattern2
./file1
./file4
pattern3
./file1
./file2
./file4
```

Note that in order not to match `patternsFile.txt` itself, you need to add it one directory up (as shown in the above examples).

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `awk`:

```bash
awk '/^(pattern)/{print}' /path/to/find/*
```

`pattern` is the string you want to match in the files.

Comment: Does this traverse a directory tree, or only the files in the path specified without going into contained directories?

Comment: Doesn't work for me: `user@host:/dir$ awk '/^(getCookie)/{print}' .
awk: warning: command line argument `.' is a directory: skipped`

Answer (score 3):

Go to the directory.
For search, then search your text by -> `grep -r "yoursearchtext"`

Now you should see all files which has matching text.

Then go to file → `less fileName`

Then read the file's full text → <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>

Then search the text in the file → `?+yousearchText`

Then search all matching case → <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

After checking the alternatives for a desktop, I wrote an open-source GUI program for full text search. It's blazing fast in comparison with *grep* flavors.

You can check it at *[Missing Linux GUI app to full-text search files](https://github.com/sergeych/raysearch)*. It can search for both content and file names in a intuitive search string, so you can look for "license mit *.md" and get few false positives ;)

Comment: What kind of desktop? What is it based on? What was it tested on? What are the dependencies for it to run? What Linux flavours does it work on? What Linux flavours does it *not* work on?

Comment: We use it at Ubuntu 22.04 and 23.04, also it got some testing under windows by one enthusiast. It is written using compose for desktop (native graphics and kotlin logick) so should work on all falvours, I'll greatly appreciate any reports. I use it daily and plan to add indexing external archive volumes with offline search (u23.04). It is expected to run with no deps being packed together in a big .deb package.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit and use like this:

```
find /your-path -type f -exec grep -l 'text-to-find-here' {} +
```