# How to find all files which include few specific strings but not necessarily in the same line?

Tags: linux, grep, find

In linux `grep -r <string> <path>` is a common way to find all instances of  in files under `<path>`, which basically gives you all the files under `<path>` which include `<string>`. But what if I want to find all files which include few strings? From `grep -r <string1> <path> | grep <string2>` I can get all files which include `<string1>` and `<string2>` in the same line, but how can I get the files which include `<string1>` and `<string2>` in separate lines?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/finding-all-files-containing-a-text-string-in-linux/20950539#20950539

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try

```
grep -rl searchstring1 . | xargs grep -l searchstring2
```

to get a list of file names in directory `.` containing both `searchstring`s (not necessarily in the same line).  You can cascade that in case you want more search strings:

```
grep -rl searchstring1 . \
  | xargs grep -l searchstring2 \
  | xargs grep -l searchstring3
```

This is tricky in case you have spaces and other nasty characters in the file names because then the `xargs` gets fooled.  In such special cases (or just to be sure not to get that problem) you can use 0-byte terminated strings:

```
grep -rlZ searchstring1 . \
  | xargs -0 grep -lZ searchstring2 \
  | xargs -0 grep -l searchstring3
```

And to check the output you can use sth like:

```
grep -rlZ searchstring1 . \
  | xargs -0 grep -lZ searchstring2 \
  | xargs -0 grep -lZ searchstring3 \
  | xargs -0 egrep 'searchstring2|searchstring2|searchstring3' /dev/null \
  | less
```

A completely different approach is using `find` straight forward (but that starts lots of `grep` processes and is therefore probably less efficient):

```
find . -type f \( \
  -exec grep -q searchstring1 {} \; -a \
  -exec grep -q searchstring2 {} \; -a \
  -exec grep -q searchstring2 {} \; \) -print
```

Comment: `xargs` is a good option, this will work certainly and I will accept your answer, but are there alternatives? What I'm saying is that looking for files with few strings is a very basic problem and I would expect it could be solved without pipes. This is a scalability issue, ideally, I'm looking for a similar syntax to `<command and flags I'm looking for> <list of strings> <path>`. For simplicity we can assume that all strings are normal alpha numeric characters

Comment: I added a `find` version in case you prefer that.  Other options I could think of would involve using Python or similar.  I can't think of a third way using just Unix standard tools.

Comment: All in all I think your answer is sufficient, however, I'll be glad to hear answers which don't include pipes

Comment: I'm just curious:  What is your objection against pipes grounded on?

Comment: As I said, first scalability, and the second is that it seems to me that it only makes sense to have a command or a flag which will handle this specific case. Even your first approach is almost as scalable as a pipe free solution but for readability and ease of use I prefer a single designated command

Comment: Be aware that on multicore processors nowadays it often has advantages to split tasks into several separate processes.  But I see your point.