# Unix: Searching for a word in files situated at different paths

Tags: linux, shell, unix

My requirenment is to Search the logs and find some specific entry. Log files are situated at two different paths. And I want to search in both.

Usually I login to server, go to the path and execute grep -i *word* *filename*

I want to prepare a script which will accept input from users for word and filename and search for it.

Comment: this should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/finding-all-files-containing-a-text-string-in-linux

Answer (score 3):

You can search in as many paths as you want:

```
grep -i "word" *filename* /some/other/path/*filename*
```

Comment: _as many paths as you want_ - up to shell's maximum command line length. Possible easily reach when here is many logfiles with `/some/very/long/path/name/*files.log`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should help

```
#!/bin/sh
#Purpose: To find a given text in a file
if [ -z "$3" ]
then
  echo Usage: $0 DirectoryToSearchIn testToSearch filePattern  
  exit 1 
fi

find $1  -name '$3' | while read f
do   
  cat "$f" | grep "$3" && echo "[in $f]"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

With `find` and `grep` you can do it over multiple directories (without knowning the directory name before)

```
find /path/to/files -type f -name '*filename*' -exec grep -i word /dev/null {} \;
```

This example finds files that contain *filename* (but could be anything) . I also added a sample path but you can use `.` in order to start the search in the current directories. The `-type f` returns files (not directories).

OR you can use recursive grep, as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16957078/2327328).

```
grep -rnw 'directory' -e "*filename*"
```

Comment: you should change `grep -i word {} \;` into  `-exec grep -i word /dev/null {} \;` (ie, add "-exec ", and also provide an additionnal (empty) file to grep so that it will output the filename in which he found occurences of "word".) This is the portable way (ie, not using GNU grep additionnal options to always display the filename)