# Linux command to search for a name which has reference in multiple files inside same dir

Tags: linux

Can some one tell me the Linux command to search for any name that has referenced inside in any of the files in the directory?
eg : I need to search for a script say abc.sh that has reference in any other scripts in the same directory. So I need the list of all scripts where the abc.sh has a reference.

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean with "reference"? A is referenced by B if the name of A is written inside B? Or you are referring to symbolic links?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding all files containing a text string on Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/finding-all-files-containing-a-text-string-on-linux)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to get the list:

```
grep -l abc.sh  *
```

Comment: Thanks, But can you tell me what -l is used for ?

Comment: It tells `grep` to only show the NAMES of the files rather than the complete lines on which your string occurs. Type `man grep` and then hit SPACEBAR to read through the manual for `grep`.