# Insecure content. How to change google font url globally in template

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl, themes

I'm using a theme on a wordpress site that has this url: href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/ (this makes the ssl pages insecure).

I need to change the above link globally to this url:  href='//fonts.googleapis.com/ (this link makes the ssl pages secure).

This one link is on all the pages of my website including, the registration page and login page.  The content at my website is insecure because of this link and a warning message is stated to visitors, that this website content is not secure and your information could get replaced or hacked.

I was able to change this link in one place in the child theme.  Now that one page is secure. I viewed the source and found the insecure link that is coming from the template not the web pages.  I used whynopadlock.com which showed me the insecure link.  I sent message to support and no answer yet.  How do I globally change this one link in wordpress theme?  I'm using wordpress version 4.0 and the theme is Evolve Lite.  I want to keep this theme if I can fix the problem.  I'm a newbie and I know very little php.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when changing adding SSL encription, I had to:

[`grep -rnw '[WordPress PATH]' -e 'http://fonts.googleapis.com'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/how-to-find-all-files-containing-specific-text-on-linux)

Finding:

> [WordPress PATH]/wp-content/plugins/wp-frontpage-news/inc/wp-fpn-    main.inc.php:274: `$myFontsUrl   =   'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?' .`

This helped me find the file I had to change.

King regards!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the theme it seems that the Google Fonts link is hard coded in two places.

Line 155 of options-framework.php which can be found at evolve/library/functions/options-framework.php

```
wp_enqueue_style('google-fonts', "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:r,b|Cabin:r,b,i");
```

And also line 98 of functions.php found at evolve/library/functions/functions.php

```
 wp_enqueue_style('googlefont', "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=".$font_face_all);
```

Try changing those over to https or just //fonts.~ as you mention and all should be fine. Bear in mind that if the theme updates it may switch these values back again as they are core theme files looking at the location of them.

Comment: It worked.  You are a genius. Thanks a lot Dan Purdy.  My website is secure now.

Comment: Great, glad it helped you. As i mentioned, keep and eye on it if you update the theme. Could you accept the answer please?