# Editing an inbuilt(?) transactional email variable in magento

Tags: php, email, magento, magento-1.7

I am new to Magento, and my same [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/48883/adding-google-analytics-tracking-code-to-product-links-in-abandoned-cart-email) on Magento stack exchange didn't get proper response, so I am posting this on the mighty SO now.

**Background**

I have installed an Abandoned Cart extension in my Magento CE 1.7 store and I have problem configuring the transactional email sent to remind people of their abandoned carts.

Here's how the relevant part of the default email template looks:

```
<p><strong>Hello {{var customer_name}},</strong></p>
<p>Thank you for stopping by {{var website_name}} and considering us for your purchase. We noticed that during your visit to our store you placed the following item(s) in your shopping cart, but did not complete the transaction.</p>
<p>Shopping Cart Contents: </p>
<p>{{var products}}</p>

{{depend real_quote}}
<!-- <p><a href="{{var recover_url}}" >Recover </a><br> (url:{{var recover_url}})</p> -->
{{/depend}} 

{{depend coupon}}
    <p>Please use this coupon: {{var coupon}} to avail 5% discount on your order value</p>
    <p>Please note that it expires in {{var coupon_days}} day(s)</p>
{{/depend}}
```

Note the `{{var products}}` that was used in the email. This thing prints the product details in the email (name, image, link to product etc).

**Question**

I need to change the product url that gets printed. I have some analytics code to append to these URLs and I can't figure out where this `var products` is defined to change its behavior.

**Things I have tried**:

- tried to print `{{var product_name}}` and other product variables as
  defined [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/system_email_template/index), but they all ended up as blank spaces
- found a good [resource](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/11/25/magento-advanced-transactional-email-templates/) that has info about changing these
  variables, but couldn't figure out how to use that to change this
  products variable
- added utm parameters after `{{var products}}` only to get the utm text
  after product details table (defined somewhere as products).

I am not even sure if this `{{var products}}` is an inbuilt variable or something defined by the extension?

EDIT: The `products` is not a custom variable. Don't know if that would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out myself, and wanted to post the answer.

The code that generates the `products` is in the models of the third-party extension I've installed for sending the cart emails. I have too many extensions installed, and couldn't find this one easily.

I understood that all the extension related code is in `app/code/local/<extension-name>/Cartalert`. (the Cartalert directory would be named differently depending on the extension). I did this by `grep`ing through my repository searching for "Save and Send out" text, which is used in CMS for manually sending these emails.

```
grep -Ril "Save and Send out" <directory>
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16956810/1076075) was my reference. Also, if you're dealing with custom emails like me, [this](https://www.ashsmith.io/2014/08/28/custom-transactional-emails-in-magento/) would help.

Next I went to the model where these alerts are being generated, which was in `app/local/<extension-name>/Cartalert/Model/Cartalert.php`

This was the relevant code I had to change.

```
for ($i=0, $n=sizeof($prod); $i<$n; $i+=2){
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->setStoreId($this->getStoreId())
                ->load($prod[$i]);
            if(in_array($product->getStatus(),$status)&&in_array($product->getVisibility(),$visibility)&&$product->isSaleable())
            {
                $url = $baseUrl . 'catalog/product/view/id/'.$prod[$i];
                $name = $prod[$i+1];
```

I had to append the parameters to the `$url` string, and it got the job done. Never thought `grep` would help me more than the docs... :D