# Possible to search through all JSPs in Adobe CQ5 repository with CRXDE?

Tags: adobe, aem, jackrabbit, jcr, crx

We have a couple of relatively simple websites running on Adobe CQ 5.5 that were developed by a third party.  I'm pretty familiar with how CQ works, but I'm working with somebody else's code here and I need to be able to search through all components in the system for a particular string.

The issue is that I can't seem to find a way to search across all of the various .jsp files stored with the various system components.  I would have figured that the query tool in CRXDE Lite would have done the trick with something like this:

```
/jcr:root//*[jcr:contains(., 'Find this exact string in a JSP')] order by @jcr:score
```

But I've had no luck.

What I am looking for is some sort of global search that includes JSP files.  Is that possible?  Were I using a regular Java system, any IDE worth the download would be able to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are on linux, then you can explore this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/finding-all-files-containing-a-text-string-on-linux

Answer (score 0):

Might not be easiest way, but you can use the [VLT tool](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/crx/current/how_to/how_to_use_the_vlttool.html) to checkout the repository into your filesystem. Then you can lookup using whatever tool you prefer. It might even be faster in the long run

Comment: That's certainly not an answer to the query question, but that's a darn useful tool to have in your back pocket in any case.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the actual answer but I suppose the JSPs are indexed via a filter that strips out some of their content.

It should be possible to configure the repository to index them as is instead, based on the info at http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/IndexingConfiguration and http://jackrabbit.apache.org/jackrabbit-text-extractors.html

Sorry about the vagueness of this answer - I know the basic principles but to provide the details I would need more time than I can afford now ;-)