# Search File with SSL in Linux

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I want to search All .java files in current directory and subdirectories that ends with .java and have text "SSL" in that file.
Any help on this??
 I tried grep -rnq  -e "SSL" but its taking so much time.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: All ".java" files end with ".java", and how is this question related to "Java" tag?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/finding-all-files-containing-a-text-string-on-linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must use find to improve your search and then you grep it

for FILE in $(find -name *.java);do grep SSL $FILE > /dev/null && echo $FILE;done

or

find . -name '*.java' | xargs grep "SSL" -sl

Comment: what is dev/null here??