# How to grep for value in a key-value store from plain text

Tags: linux, shell, unix, grep

Given a plain text file containing

```
FOO=foo
BAR=bar
BAZ=baz
```

How do we `grep` for the value using the key?

Comment: A dirty alternative: If the file looks like what your have pasted, source the file and use $BAR, $BAZ directly. PS: Dont follow this suggestion, you'll instantly encounter many corner cases.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use a [look behind](https://regex101.com/r/q3FNpe/1):

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=^FOO=)\w*$' file
foo
```

I also like `awk` for it:

```
$ awk -v FS="FOO=" 'NF>1{print $2}' file
foo
```

Or even better:

```
$ awk -F= -v key="FOO" '$1==key {print $2}' file
foo
```

With `sed`:

```
$ sed -n 's/^FOO=//p' file
foo
```

Or even with Bash -ONLY if you are confident about the file not containing any weird values-, you can source the file and `echo` the required value:

```
$ (source file; echo "$FOO")
foo
```

Comment: these are quite common tools with common approaches. If anybody needs some explanation, just ping me and I will add them!

Comment: `sed` does the job quite well.

Comment: how to grep a value from FOO in entire path instead of giving a particular file?

Comment: @NandhaKumar you may want to check [How do I find all files containing specific text on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16956810/1983854)

Comment: Careful with `awk -v FS="FOO="` because it will return the value for any keys with partial matches; e.g.: `echo -en 'AFOO=oops\nFOO=bar' | awk -v FS='FOO=' 'NF>1{print $2}'` returns both `oops` and `bar`. Use `FS='^FOO='` to get the exact match.

Comment: I love the sed answer

Answer (score 11):

## Simple way:

```bash
grep "^FOO=" | cut -d"=" -f2-
```

I prefer this because it's very easy to remember for me.

**Explanation:** It simply greps the line starting with `FOO` (hence the `^`) and cutting it with `=` to pieces and then getting the second piece with `-f2-`.

Comment: Beware that this won't return the correct value if the value has `=` in it. E.g.: `echo 'FOO=bar=oops' | grep "^FOO=" | cut -d"=" -f2` incorrectly returns `bar`. Using `f-2-` returns the correct value `bar=oops`

Comment: This is the perfect answer if you make little modification like what @ThiagoFigueiro told. (it has been 4 years).

Comment: I tried to update the answer 4 years ago but SO doesn't allow 1-character changes so ‍♂️

Comment: Using `f-2-`, as suggested in a comment above, seems to be wrong. Using `-f2-` works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one too...

```
grep "^FOO=" file.txt | awk -F"=" '{ print $2 }'
```

With some help from @fedorqui

Comment: `grep` + `awk` normally means that `awk` alone can handle it. Also, what if we have a line `hello=FOO`? This would return `FOO`, whereas `hello` is not the given key.

Comment: To make it works always, use `^FOO=`. This way, it will match the beginning of the line.

Comment: Ah thanks, I didn’t knew that! I was trying to help someone with a doubt, and I was the one that ended up learning something! Thanks @fedorqui!

Comment: This won't work when you have value like this (as seen in complex password): `echo 'FOO==FO=bar=oo==ps=pk' | grep "^FOO=" | awk -F"=" '{ print $2 }'`, it returns nothing. it should return `=FO=bar=oo==ps=pk`. I think the best answer when using grep is from @Inanc Gumus with little modification from @Thiago's comment

Answer (score 0):

Another proposition : split the work

```
grep "FOO=" file.txt | sed -e 's/.*=//'
```

`grep` will fetch the correct lines

`sed` will remove anything up to the (last) equal sign

Comment: Try this and you will be disappointed with this answer: `echo 'FOO==FO=bar=oo==ps=pk' | grep "FOO=" | sed -e 's/.*=//'` This should return `=FO=bar=oo==ps=pk` but it returns only `pk`