# Google Analytics Receiving Data -- but no analytics in view source

Tags: google-analytics

My client created a website and a google analytics account. The report indicates that the account is receiving data -- and yet, when we do a view-source of the pages of the site, there is definitely absolutely no analytics code there. How is this posssible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that the Analytics code is added via Javascript, not appearing in the "View Source" page. It is also possible for it not to appear in the inspector either.

I do not know how this happens, but I have encountered scripts that exist and run although they are not displayed in either the source page or the live DOM inspector (in Google Chrome). This happened to me while loading a PHP template containing Javascript through an Ajax request.

If you have access to the source code of your website, search the entire project for for the Analytics ID (Here's how to find it: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032385?hl=en), and you'll locate your tracking code.

If your project is running on a Linux server, here's a post about how to quickly find a keyword (like the Analytics ID) in a folder: [How do I find all files containing specific text on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/finding-all-files-containing-a-text-string-on-linux)