# Searching/Finding C/C++ Source but not Headers

Tags: macos, shell, ack

I tried `ack -f --cpp --nohh` but it returns no results.

I'm using 2.14 on OSX.

Comment: what about good old find? `find . -type f -name '*.cpp'`

Comment: @incBrain 'find' is an old friend. Just trying to learn a new tool. Also I eventually want to search for content within just the .cpp files.

Comment: I use grep to do this. `grep -rnw . --include=\*.{cpp,cc} -e 'std::cout'` . [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16957078/3734222) explains it really well. But learning new things is always a good idea. I never heard about `ack` thank you for this, I also will take a look at it :)

Comment: Ugh. My bad. The directory tree only had .c and .h. `ack -f --cc --nohh` lists only .c as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I apparently misread the question.  I thought that the question implied that the user was seeing source files but not headers.    If the desire is to show source files but not headers, the command stream   *ack -f --cpp --nohh* should  give the desired results and works for me.  However, I have a number of samples of C and C++ code in my personal directory.  What is your working directory when running the command?  Do you have source and header files  in your directory.

I am sorry if I misread your question.

http://beyondgrep.com is the web site for ack

... Previous answer

if you look at man ack, --nohh means to not include header files.

I just ran 
ack -f --hh --cpp
on my Mac OS X with ack 2.12 and a great many header files appeared.

...

I am using Mac OS X El Capitan (Version 10.11.5) with ack 2.12

Comment: The title of the question is: **Searching/Finding C/C++ Source but not Headers**

Comment: See my comment on the question--user error. Thanks to Bradley for kicking me out of my dumb-dumb orbit.