# How can I get the number of XML files containing a specific phrase?

Tags: regex, xml, linux, grep

I have a directory containing XML files which contain information about cartoons. For example, a cartoon can be a simple "Cartoon" or a "Cartoon Sketch" and so on.

When I apply the following command, then I get all XML files containing the phrase "Cartoon Sketch":

```
grep -R --files-with-matches --include="*.xml" "Cartoon Sketch" /path/to/dir | nl
```

But when I change the above command to get all XML files containing the word "Cartoon" as follows:

```
grep -R --files-with-matches --include="*.xml" "Cartoon" /path/to/dir | nl
```

then I get also all the files containing the phrase "Cartoon Sketch".

How can I limit the result just to files containing "Cartoon" but not "Cartoon Sketch"?

Comment: please show some [mcve], otherwise we cannot know how your data is structured.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding all files containing a text string on Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/finding-all-files-containing-a-text-string-on-linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another `grep -v` to excludes lines matching "Sketch"

`grep -R --files-with-matches --include="*.xml" "Cartoon" /path/to/dir | grep -v "Sketch" | wc -l`