# "grep -rnw": search for a string in all files

Tags: linux, grep, find, full-text-search

Related question: [How do I find all files containing specific text on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/finding-all-files-containing-a-text-string-on-linux)

I have been using the command mentioned in the answer of above question to search for string occurences in all files:

```
grep -rnw '/path/to/somewhere/' -e "pattern"
```

However lately I encountered a problem, shown in the following picture:
[image]

Looks like this command only recognizes strings that stand out as a word or something. How should I modify the command to improve my search result?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

[explainshell](http://www.explainshell.com) helpfully explains your command, and gives an excerpt from `man grep`:

```
   -w, --word-regexp
          Select  only  those  lines  containing matches that form whole words.
```

So just remove `-w` since that explicitly does what you don't want:

```
grep -rn '/path/to/somewhere/' -e "pattern"
```

Comment: Be advised, "pattern" is a regexp.

Comment: Thank you. Additionally, `-r, --recursive`, `-n, --line-number`