# How to find all files containing specific text (which includes a backslash)?

Tags: linux, text, grep, find, escaping

I thought I found the perfect answer with [How do I find all files containing specific text on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/how-to-find-all-files-containing-specific-text-on-linux), so I tried it:

```
[Michael@devserver ~]$ grep -rnw '/var/www/concrete5.7.5.9/' -e "Concrete\Core\Block\BlockController"
[Michael@devserver ~]$
```

None show, but I know there should have been a match.

```
[Michael@devserver ~]$ grep -rnw '/var/www/concrete5.7.5.9/concrete/blocks/html' -e "BlockController"
/var/www/concrete5.7.5.9/concrete/blocks/html/controller.php:5:use \Concrete\Core\Block\BlockController;
/var/www/concrete5.7.5.9/concrete/blocks/html/controller.php:7:class Controller extends BlockController
[Michael@devserver ~]$
```

I also tried escaping the backslash to no avail.

```
[Michael@devserver ~]$ grep -rnw '/var/www/concrete5.7.5.9/' -e "Concrete\\Core\\Block\\BlockController"
[Michael@devserver ~]$
```

Also tried single quotes to no avail.

```
[Michael@devserver ~]$ grep -rnw '/var/www/concrete5.7.5.9/' -e 'Concrete\Core\Block\BlockController'
[Michael@devserver ~]$
```

How to find all files containing specific text which includes a backslash on Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quotes and escape backslash.

```
grep -rnw '/var/www/concrete5.7.5.9/' -e'Concrete\\Core\\Block\\BlockController'
```

Comment: Yea, that is what I found as well.  What does the `-e` do?  Thanks

Comment: -e  takes a regexp pattern, backslash is escape character in regexp, so you have to put 2 backslashes in order to scape backslash, if you use double quotes you have to use 4 backslaches , because backslash is the scape character in bash too.

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes.

```
grep -rnw '/var/www/concrete5.7.5.9/' -e 'Concrete\Core\Block\BlockController'
```

Comment: Had already tried it, but no go.  But then I went one step further and tried to use single quotes and escape the backslashes with another backslash!  Maybe should update your answer?  Thanks!

Comment: I thought about it, but was lazy to check.

Comment: Turns out they are needed.  What had stumped me was I had to both change from double to single quotes and escape the backslashes.  I tried each, but not at the same time :(

Answer (score 0):

Grep has an option `-F` to interpret the pattern literally and not as a regular expression. For example:

```
$ cat infile
use \Concrete\Core\Block\BlockController;
class Controller extends BlockController
$ grep 'Concrete\Core\Block\BlockController' infile     # No match!
$ grep -F 'Concrete\Core\Block\BlockController' infile  # Matches!
use \Concrete\Core\Block\BlockController;
```