# Searching in linux/unix

Tags: linux, bash, unix, search, grep

I'm in a bash terminal. I'm cd'd to a folder (web application folder)

I'm looking for a file. I know it exists. I don't know under which sub sub.. folder. All I know is that inside the file these words appear:
"carousel"  "javascript" "chart"

How can I find this file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find all files containing specific text on Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/how-to-find-all-files-containing-specific-text-on-linux)

Answer (score 2):

Try to run this command if you want to find the file containing any of these words:

```
grep -rE 'foo1|foo2' .
```

If you want to find the file containing all of these words,

try this:

```
grep -r 'foo1' .|grep 'foo2'
```

If you want to find multiple strings in file on different lines,

you can use

```
grep -rl 'foo1' .|xargs grep -l 'foo2'
```

-r

> For each directory operand, read and process all files in that
>   directory, recursively. Follow symbolic links on the command line, but
>   skip symlinks that are encountered recursively. Note that if no file
>   operand is given, grep searches the working directory.

-E

> Use pattern as the pattern. If this option is used multiple times or
>   is combined with the -f (--file) option, search for all patterns
>   given. (-e is specified by POSIX.)

You can read [GNU Grep 2.27](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/grep/manual/grep.html) to learn more about `grep`.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I did upvote because this is the right "direction" but please note OP is looking for a file containing ALL those words (not any of them)

Comment: @mauro Thank you for reminding me.I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To search from current directory downward through all directories try this:

```
find . -type f -exec egrep 'carousel|javascript|chart' {} \; -print
```

This will *find* ALL text files that contain your chosen words.
If you know a specific file extension you want to search for you can modify it like so to search for Python files:

```
find . -name '*.py' -type f -exec egrep 'carousel|javascript|chart' {} \; -print
```

Answer (score 0):

If you search all the files with carousel **and** javascript **and** chart you can try :

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'grep -q carousel $1 && grep -q javascript $1 && grep -q chart $1 && echo $1' sh {} \;
```

Example :

```
$ cat a.txt
carousel
javascript
chart

$ cat b.txt
carousel
chart
```

Result :

```
./a.txt
```