# How to list files which contain specific string using linux commands

Tags: linux, search

I need to list files from a directory which contains a specific string using linux commands.

Comment: contain in the filename or inside? text files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find all files containing specific text on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/how-do-i-find-all-files-containing-specific-text-on-linux)

Answer (score 10):

Use the command

```sh
grep -inr <string> /path/to/directory
```

The `-inr` option has three parts:

- `i` to ignore case sensitivity,
- `n` to display the line numbers in for each matched result, and
- `r` to recursively read all files under each directory.

Comment: `/path/to/directory` would actually be path to the file if you are looking in this directory itself with no recursion required. remove `-r` also. If name of the file is not know then `*.*`

Comment: how to make it `not` display the substring in result output? eg only output = filenames, nothing else

Comment: @parsecer You can use the lower L tag `grep -l` (files-with-matches) for that. This also skips the rest of the file on the first match so that could be a performance improvement.

Answer (score 4):

Let say your string is in the environment variable `STR` and you search in directory `dir/`. You can do:

```
find dir/ -type f -name "*${STR}*"
```

If you search a file containing the string:

```
find dir/ -type f -exec grep -l $STR {} \;
```

But this is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/how-do-i-find-all-files-containing-specific-text-on-linux)

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
grep -nr <string> <path to the directory>
```

This will print the name of the files with the line number containing the string

If you want to list file name(s) with a particular string then do

```
find <path to the directory> -iname <string_pattern> -type f
```

Answer (score 0):

This command will find files with matching string. 
However, I added little more extra, exec will list the files.

**command**

```
find <your/dir/> -name "string_to_search*" -type f -exec ls -l {} \;
```

or this command will list all the c files in your directory.

```
find <your/dir/> -name "*.c" -type f -exec ls -l {} \;
```

---

Using find command to find the matching string inside the file.

```
find  -type f | xargs grep 'text-to-find-here'
```

Here `/` means search in all dirs

```
find / -type f | xargs grep 'text-to-find-here'
```

or

```
grep -r "string to be searched"  /path/to/dir
```

Comment: You want to list the files from directory?

Comment: i want to list the files from the directory which contains specific string for example : if a file contain 57690 it should be listed

Comment: alright use the first command I mentioned in my question, that will do the job.