# How to find string in file within current directory?

Tags: string, file, unix, directory, string-matching

Is it possible to search within a directory to scan all files for a particular string, then return the file(s) if the string is found?

For example I am looking to try find files where "120854" is found. If we take the below example using a directory called */users/TCP/* that contains two files called File1 and File2.

```
File1
-----
Product1:432153
Product2:8614
Product3:975

File2
-----
Product76:87
Product324:684
Product965:120854
```

The expected outcome would return **/users/TCP/File2** as "120854" is found on line 3 in that file. Obviously the directory I'm using has thousands of files and therefore wondering if this is possible. Can't find anything online myself

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate ?! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/how-do-i-find-all-files-containing-specific-text-on-linux

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find all files containing specific text on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/how-do-i-find-all-files-containing-specific-text-on-linux)

Answer (score 0):

**grep -Ril "120854" /users/TCP/**

-- `R` stands for recursive.

-- `i` stands for ignore case (optional in your case).

-- `l` stands for "show the file name, not the result itself".

-- `/users/TCP/` stands for directory you are searching in