# Two-layer search in Atom

Tags: search, grep, atom-editor

Currently in atom I can search for a string in my project, but is there a way to search for a string in my projects, then search for a string in those files found in the first search?

I want to be able to find all uses of a function in a class, but the problem is that the class can have any name in files(thank you Javascript). So I know which files import my class based on the file location which gets imported, but I don't have any way of searching those results for the string 'getOrder'. For example I would like to be able to do the following:

- search for the string 'meals/meals'
- get a list of file names
- use those file names and search for the string '.getOrder'

I think this is doable with grep, but I am no master of grep. I tried that route and failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grep a grep by feeding into the grep command with `$()`:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20262/how-do-i-pass-a-list-of-files-to-grep

and this guy showed me how to get a list of files that contain the string I need:

[How do I find all files containing specific text on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/how-do-i-find-all-files-containing-specific-text-on-linux)

which gives you

```
grep createOrder $(grep -rnwl './' -e 'meals/meals')
```