# How to find a file containing specific text in Centos7?

Tags: linux, centos7

I have a server which runs on centos 7. I need to find a file containing 0774386850 so that I can replace with another string. Kindly give me a Linux command to give me that file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find all files containing specific text on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/how-do-i-find-all-files-containing-specific-text-on-linux)

Comment: Did you put someone's mobile number in your question?...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

By using `grep` command, you can achieve what you expected

```
grep -rlnw '/path/to/somewhere/' -e '0774386850'
-r or -R is recursive,
-n is line number, and
-w stands for match the whole word.
-l (lower-case L) file name of matching files.
```

Answer (score 3):

grep -r "0774386850 "  /path/to/dir

Answer (score 0):

You can use either **grep**/**fgrep** or **find** to achieve your goal.

Comment: find /path/to/files -type f -exec sed -i 's/oldstring/new string/g' {} \;