# Find a String in all Files with a certain name in Mac Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

I am looking for a way to find all "info.plist"-files that contain "iphonesimulator" in my directory and all subdirectories.

I know that I can find all "iphonesimulator" via:

```
grep -ri "iphonesimulator" .
```

But that is not everything that I want. Is there a way to also filter for files? I tried with -f but that does not work.

Comment: Do you mean you want to find the *names of the files* containing that string? Or do you mean you want to see all the *lines containing that string* in those files?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I want the Terminal to show me the directory to the files named info.plist (because there are quite a few of it) that contain the String "iphonesimulator". I need this because I have to replace them by "iPhoneOS" for the deploy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
find <root_directory> -name '<file_matching_pattern>' -exec cat {} \; -exec grep --colour -i 'text_matching_pattern' {} \;
```

For your particular example:

```
find / -name info.plist -exec cat {} \; -exec grep --colour -i '*iphonesimulator*' {} \;
```

or you can just ignore file name pattern and do it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/how-do-i-find-all-files-containing-specific-text-on-linux)