# How to find files that are N level deep in a log file

Tags: linux, command

I'm trying to find files in a log file that are 2 levels deep from the root (eg. /xxx/xxx/xxx.xxx). I tried "find" and maxdepth, mindepth but that was only useful for files in directories. I need to find strings in a file instead and discard any results that are more than 2 levels.

Answer (score 0):

[How do I find all files containing specific text on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/how-do-i-find-all-files-containing-specific-text-on-linux) seems to do what you want. It's unclear to me if you have matches you want to discard if they are deeper that two levels.

Comment: Yes I need to discard the other matches. My purpose is to see how many I have that are 2 deep.