# Find and replace string in putty

Tags: linux, ssh

I want to migrate a domain from a server to another. I want to find and replace all the strings with the old name with the new one using `ssh`. What is the right command in putty?

For example find John inside the files of a folder and rename it with Bill

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find all files containing specific text on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/how-do-i-find-all-files-containing-specific-text-on-linux)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Answer (score -1):

for replacing single file you can use

```
sed -i -e 's/John/Bill/g' /tmp/file.txt
```

and for searching files you can use

```
find . -name "*.txt" -print
```

when you combine them with -exec, you will get the result which you are looking for.

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec sed -i -e 's/John/Bill/g' {} +
```

Comment: no. you need to use last command that I provided. Just change "*.txt" part and 's/John/Bill/g' part