# How to Find a String Among Thousands of Code Pages?

Tags: php, linux, cpanel

Lets say you downloaded a free PHP script from GitHub and it has thousands of PHP files, language files, etc.

Now if you need to customize a specific line of code and you don't know where it is located, you have to go through each file to find where it belongs to and after spending a huge amount of time, you may be lucky to find it.

Is there any way to find the code faster (offline or in cPanel)?

Comment: It is possible with standard "Find in Path..." function of JetBrains IDEs, e.g.

Comment: do you know the `string` in question ?

Comment: yes, let's say you know the exact string that you looking for

Comment: for example: "Welcome to your profile"

Comment: I use PhpStorm, which will find that. On a mac : spotlight will also find all files with that string ... which also has a 'nix shell which will also do that ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/how-do-i-find-all-files-containing-specific-text-on-linux)

Comment: If you're getting it off Github, Github lets you search the contents of an entire repository via the search bar up top.

Comment: all good IDE's have a file search function

Comment: I have a very small script that does this, I think I wrote it in php, perl, .net, asp, and maybe python too, so whatever version you want, just tell me. what it does, give it... a directory, or compressed file, and the file types to edit, and search and replace strings or an array of search terms, or hash references and it will do the replacements automatically, or you can verify each replacement presented in a form. It also keeps track of the replacements so you can revert changes as many times as you have previously edited a file as long as you don't delete the log file.

Comment: if you know the function name, a variable name, etc then `man grep`  Otherwise learn how to use a debugger with break points and watch values

Comment: As I can't delete the question, I'll ask you for permission for this question to stay. BTW thanks for the tip.

Comment: @KevinSmith Github **absolutely** can search within the code. For example: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/search?q=%22%24user-%3Eid%22

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes, I just know that option. Thanks so much mate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally have used PHiSearch a lot to search through folders of code & usually get a hit for what I'm looking for.