# How do I find all files containing specific text on Linux but not in subdirectories?

Tags: linux, grep

Surprisingly i could not find an answer without sub directories. ie I guess without the `-R` option. What I was looking for was to search for text in a directory but avoid searching in subdirectories.
[Original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/how-do-i-find-all-files-containing-specific-text-on-linux)

Tried

```
grep -nl 'text' /search/path/
```

But I get the error:

```
'search/path/ Is a directory`
```

Whereas if I try with:

```
grep -rnl 'text' /search/path/` --exclude-dir *
```

It still searched through subdirectories.

Comment: `grep -nl "text" /search/path/*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```sh
grep 'text' /search/path/*
#                        ^
```

The `*` will expand to all the elements in the directory and the absence of `-R` will avoid going deeper into subdirectories.

The drawback of this approach is that it will exclude the hidden files, since `.files` do not expand with `*` alone. If you also want to grep those, you can use:

```sh
grep 'text' /search/path/{*,.*}
#                        \____/
```

This way you will get all elements matching `*` and `.*` which is everything.

Finally, if you do not want to get the error message:

> search/path/ Is a directory

You can redirect it to /dev/null as follows:

```sh
grep 'text' /search/path/{*,.*} 2>/dev/null
#                               \_________/
```