# Need help fo find a global variable in Wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal

I have a Wordpress website which uses many page templates written in php and saved in a child theme. One of the theme pages deals with payments to PayPal for order on the site. There is no PayPal plugin in use just php code. The following code is include in this page

```
<form action="<?php echo $paypal_url; ?>" method="post" name="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo PAYPAL_ID; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Poem from P&P">

    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?php echo $post_id; ?>">
```

My question is where will I find the PAYPAL_ID stored.

I’ve checked in all the theme page templates and searches throughout the child theme including function.php also checked wp-config.php but no sign of where I might change the paypal account.
There is also a similar line of code regarding SANDBOX being set can’t find that either.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could login via ssh and maybe try this if you're on a linux os https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/how-do-i-find-all-files-containing-specific-text-on-linux

Comment: Heimdals sidste vogter Thanks for your suggestion I have checked it out but didn't use it as wasn't sure where to enter the search. You did give me an idea though and I found a plugin "String Locator" which searched the whole WordPress directory and found my PayPal ID which had been entered in wp-config,php (missed it on my first visit ) and plugin gave line number.

Answer (score 0):

Use plugin String Locator to find "string" in Whole Wordpress Dorectory.

Found in wp-config.php