# Extract line of text from .txt file using CMD?

Tags: cmd, extract, txt

was wandering if there is a way to extract a line of text which contains certain value from a .txt file using CMD. For example using "type filepath\example.txt" will open the whole file and in my case I am working trough a software which doesn't allow CTRL+F option and .txt files are massive.
Is there any way I could specify certain word in order to get that whole line of text or to open only .txt files which have that word within them. For example I have 1000 .txt files and all of them contain the same text but only one of them has a word "EXAMPLE" in it. Could I use some command to find and open that file using CMD.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`I have 1000 .txt files and all of them contain the same text but only one of them has a word "EXAMPLE" in it. Could I use some command to find and open that file using CMD.`

a) find the file(s) that have the desired string:

```
findstr /m "EXAMPLE" *.txt
```

b) find the file (assuming, only one contains the string; else it will open all matching files) and open the file in notepad:

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('findstr /m "EXAMPLE" *.txt') do "%a"
```

c) find the one line that has the string:

```
findstr "EXAMPLE" *.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, "findstr "EXAMPLE" *.txt " is what I basically need but there is a problem. Let's say all .txt files contain text like "Number one", "Number two" etc... when I use "Number two" in this command it shows me all the files which contain "Number".. why doesn't it treat the value as a whole since it is in quotes?

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window, type `findstr /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and learn how the command you are using works. This site isn't here just so that you can depend upon others to do everything for you @milke92. _You should also learn that, as your question stipulated 'the word "EXAMPLE"', the answer above does not isolate a word, (only a substring)_.

Comment: Thank you so much @Compo This helped me find everything I need.

Answer (score 0):

The `findstr.exe` solution from Stephen would be less typing. But, using `Select-String` allows the use of a much more complete implementation of `regex`. All supported Windows systems have PowerShell available. This works in a `batch-file` run by `cmd` on `windows` and at the command prompt. Given that this would likely be put into a `batch-file`, the amount of typing is not very significant.

```
@powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    Get-ChildItem -Path '.\*.txt' ^| ^
        ForEach-Object { Select-String -Pattern 'example' -Path $_ } ^| ^
        Select-Object -Property Filename,Line
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant alternative, I agree, and I am certain someone will tell me how it could be bettered. The key is it uses basic find a string (you can set as I have to be case insensitive) in a file then **reports filename and line number**, Line [9] in this case.

[image]

```
@forfiles /m *.txt /C "cmd /c (find /n /i \"For example\" "@file"1>nul) &&if %errorlevel%==0 (find /n /i \"For example\" "@file"2>nul)"
```

When used in a batch file it could look something like this, but see caveats below

Finder$.cmd

```
@echo off & Title Find wally String in a file
set "string=where's Wally"
if not "%1"=="" set "string=%~*"

forfiles /m *.txt /C "cmd /c (find /n /i \"%string%\" "@file"1>nul) &&if %errorlevel%==0 (find /n /i \"%string%\" "@file")"

echo/ & pause & exit /b
```

[image]

**It is not perfect** but note its not case sensitive (using /i), it can readily fail if *.txt files are not plain text and as written will only accept a short unquoted string of up to 9 words ( avoid " or other punctuation). It works in local directory with *.txt, but you could alter those as require to first say `cd /d f:\mylogs` and search *.log files.

**Finally you asked to open the file** thus we can simplify for that task to call an editor like notepad or with some fetteling one that accepts line numbers (but that is another question)

```
forfiles /m *.txt /C "cmd /c (find /n /i \"%string%\" "@file"1>nul) &&if %errorlevel%==0 (notepad.exe "@file")"
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Everything below is related to unix bash terminal, so please install Linux Subsystems if you are using Windows. Or even Linux itself :)

1. You can open specific file in a text editor like Vim or Nano in terminal. They offer the "CTRL+F" function.

Below you can see me searching for the "gameId" keyword in the file `game_stats.js`, which I opened via `$ vim game_stats.js`.
[image]

P.S. To quite vim you need to type `:q` :)

2. Use `grep` command as advised in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16957078/13212398

Example for the command that recursively searches for any `.js` or `.txt` files that contains "let" in the current directory (`.`).

```
$ grep  --include=\*.{js,txt} -rnw -e "let" .

./this_test.js:18:let bob = new Person('Bob');
./this_test.js:19:let bill = new Person('Bill', bob);
./TUD-2Q-WDB/checkers-in-delft/public/javascripts/game_state.js:99:        let pieces = []
```