# In a github organization, how can I find all the code owners which match a pattern?

Tags: github, github-codeowners

In github, our organization has code-owners.

In the individual project I can

```
cat .github/CODEOWNERS
```

It says

```
# Code owners
*       @ourorg/projectname
```

How can I find all git repositories for the same owner within this org? which is ourorg/projectname

This will let me know which projects are owned by our squad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

You can use the github search function for it.
Use `org:<org-name> <teamname> path:CODEOWNERS` as search query

**Old answer**
This assumes you have all the repos checked out locally.

I ran the command from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16957078/13516981) in order to look through all the CODEOWNERS files and search for my teamname.

`grep --include=CODEOWNERS -rw '.' -e "teamname"`

Comment: @Phil My coworker just told me a better method, see my updated answer